# Looping over image rows and columns

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering

this question should be quite easy. I am studying a path tracer at the moment and I have a question about the main loop:

```
int width = 1024; int height = 768;

for (int y=0; y<height; y++){ 
  for (unsigned short x=0; x<width; x++){
```

I am wondering the reason behind using an int for looping over the rows and an unsigned short for looping over the columns. May you illuminate me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the kind of a "why" question for which the correct, and complete answer is "because." Could be any reason. Could be no reason at all, such as the original programmer being out of coffee, that particular day. Or, it could be that "height" is an int, and "width" is an unsigned short, so this avoids a compiler warning. You have to look at the entirety of this code, overall, to determine whether or not there is a particular reason.

Comment: that's a good comment! I edit the question posting that both are defined as integers! Thanks! ps: for the first half of your answer, I hope there is another explanation ahah otherwise I will just have to consider it valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage wise they both take up the same register space and buffer time.

Possible reasons could be that

- Your academics are trying to toy with you since most of their questions are a pain
- Unsigned Short is used for non-negative values between 0-65,535 limiting your width be positive and lie in this domain.

Don't use short anyways since it takes up the same 32-bit INT Register and your take up 2 extra letters to type the same shit anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I thought there was a special reason for doing this but I guess I was just wrong. Thanks!